# Text Hovering Effect plus background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to understand how this hover effect works in this webpage : http://davidoff.com/

First it will ask for your age, then you'll be able to see it.

Specifically in the News & Event Section, where the text hovers up and changes the background color.

Will appreciate any information on this.

Thanks.

Comment: please clear your question, and secondly, would you asking for the overlay effect, that show up when the mouse hover on the picture/post/

Comment: It could be, but I'm not familiar with the term that describe the effect. And yes, is that one when you pass the mouse over the pic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, the below links will help you a lot, but the basic css3 knowledge is necessary..

1) http://callmenick.com/2014/03/06/image-overlay-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions/
2) http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/
3) http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/